# How to prove this Gaussian Mixture inequality? (Fitting/Overfitting)

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Let f[x] be a Gaussian Mixture pdf with n terms of uniform weight, means $\{\mu_{1},...,\mu_{n}\}$, and corresponding variances $\{\sigma_{1},...,\sigma_{n}\} $:

$$f(x)\equiv\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_{i}^{2}}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu_{i})^{2}}{2\sigma_{i}^{2}}}$$

It seems intuitive that the log-liklihood sampled at the n Gaussian centers would be greater than (or equal to) the mean log-liklihood:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}ln(f(\mu_{j}))\geq\int f(x)ln(f(x))dx$$

This is obviously true for small variances (each $\mu_{i}$ is on top of a narrow Gaussian) and for very large variances (all the $\mu_{i}$'s are atop one broad Gaussian together), and it's been true for every set of $\mu_i$'s and $\sigma_i$'s I've generated and optimized, but I can't figure how to prove that it's always true.  Help?

Comment: You're probably missing an expectation on the l.h.s.?

Comment: @lacerbi  No, I'm not.  Nothing is missing.  On the LHS, the $f(x)$ is evaluated at the indexed $x_i$'s

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- I was too sleepy and I misread the definition.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of an extended comment, so take it as such.
Define:
$$
f(x) \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \mathcal{N}\left(x | x_i, \sigma_i^2 \right)
$$
(I am using the standard notation for Gaussian distributions).

You want to prove that:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \log f(x_i) - \int f(x) \log f(x) dx \ge 0
$$
which is
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \log f(x_i)\right\} + \mathcal{H}[f] \ge 0.
$$

Due to Jensen's inequality (see for example [Huber et al., On Entropy Approximation for Gaussian Mixture Random Vectors, 2008](http://www-personal.acfr.usyd.edu.au/tbailey/papers/mfi08_huber.pdf)),
$$
\mathcal{H}[f] \ge -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \log \int f(x) \mathcal{N}(x | x_i, \sigma_i^2) dx
= -\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \log g_i(x_i)
$$
with $g_i(x) \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j = 1}^n \mathcal{N}\left(x | x_j, \sigma_i^2 + \sigma_j^2 \right)$, which comes from the convolution of two Gaussian densities. So we get:
$$
\left\{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \log f(x_i) \right\} + \mathcal{H}[f] \ge 
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^n \log \frac{f(x_i)}{g_i(x_i)}.
$$
Interestingly, the $g_i$ are still mixtures of Gaussians with component means equal to the ones in $f$, but each component of $g_i$ has a strictly larger variance than its corresponding component in $f$.
Can you do anything with this?

Comment: Thank you.  It looks like I'd just have prove that final RHS is >=0, which also looks intuitive but tricky to prove, but this is indeed a step in the right direction.  I've seen that paper before.

Comment: It's tempting to think that final RHS is always positive, but I can't actually prove that either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it. It only takes elementary steps, although you need to combine them right.

Let's denote by $f_i$ the density of $i$-th Gaussian, that is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma_i^2}}e^{\frac{(x-\mu_i)^2}{2\sigma_i^2}}$

We  start off with Jensen's Inequality.
The function $g(x) = x log(x) $ is convex, hence we have:
$f(x) \log(f(x)) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) \log(f_i(x))$. After integrating we get:
$$
\int f(x)\log(f(x)) dx \leq \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \int f_i(x) \log(f_i(x)) dx 
$$
**Edit: The inequality below is wrong and so is the solution itself**

Now the RHS. For all $i$ we have $f \geq f_i$, so:
$$log(f(\mu_i)) \geq log(f_i(\mu_i))$$ 
Hence:
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n log(f(\mu_i)) \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n log(f_i(\mu_i))
$$
We are left to prove:
$$
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n log(f_i(\mu_i)) \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) \log(f_i(x))
$$
But we have:
$$
log(f_i(\mu_i)) = \int f_i(x) log(f_i(\mu_i)) dx \geq \int f_i(x) log(f_i(x)) dx
$$
Summing over $i$ and dividing by $n$ we get what we needed

Comment: I'm confused.  You defined a g(x) but never used it, and I don't know  what your f_i means.

Comment: I added definition of $f_i$, sorry about that. I use $g$ just for the Jensen inequality, that is $g(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)) \leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n g(f_i(x))$

Comment: You statement that $f>=f_i$ is only correct if the $1/n$ weight is part of the definition of $f_i$ but it's not, and adding it back in messes up the early part of your proof.

Comment: This statement is not correct: $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n log(f(\mu_i)) \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n log(f_i(\mu_i))$

Comment: Yeah, I realized it yesterday. Seems like this inequality is quite tough, I'll leave my answer anyway with an edit.